# VB.Net - Getting an item from collection without using loop

Tags: string, vb.net, linq, collections, lambda

I want to optimized this code:

```
dim mPolNo as new Collection(Of String)
For Each _olap As clsOLAP in cscOLAPs
     mPolNo.Add(_olap._p1.PolNo)
Next
```

(The datatype of PolNo is String)

I tried to used the Collection.Select that I dig in google.

```
mPolNo = cscOLAPs.Select(Function(x) x._p1.PolNo.ToString)
```

But I encounter error saying:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[SIPLib.ING.clsOLAP,System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.String]'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Where` returns `IEnumerable(Of String)`.
For assigning it to the `Collection(Of String)` you need to enumerate result of `Where`.

It can be done by calling `.ToList()` extension method

```
cscOLAPs.Select(Function(x) x._p1.PolNo.ToString).ToList()
```

`ToList()` can be used because `Collection(Of String)` implements `IList(Of String)` interface.

Comment: Thanks! I need to change the data type of mPolNo from Collection(Of String) to List(Of String) to make it run.